# Write more data frames to one XLS sheet

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames:

```
dfl <- list(
  df1 = data.frame(a=1:3,b=letters[5:7],c=1:3,d=letters[1:3]),
  df2 = data.frame(d=1:4,b=1:4,e=1:4,f=letters[1:4]),
  df3 = data.frame(g=letters[2:6],b=1:5,h=1:5,i=letters[1:5]),
  df4 = data.frame(j=c(1.4,2.4,3.4588),b=letters[1:3],k=1:3,l=letters[1:3],t=7:9),  
  df5 = data.frame(m=1:4,b=1:4,n=1:4,o=letters[1:4]),    
  df6 = data.frame(p=1:5,b=1:5,q=1:5,r=letters[1:5],s=4:8)
)
```

Each data frame has different number of columns, different column names and different data types. Is there any way how I can write data to XLS file (Excel) to one sheet, possibly separated with empty row or data frame name?

Currently, I'm using package `WriteXLS`, but here data frames can be written to separated sheets only:

```
library(WriteXLS)
WriteXLS("dfl",ExcelFileName="MyExcel.xls")
```

Comment: How do you want the columns to align (e.g., all left-aligned)? Probably easier to combine them all into a matrix and then write that.

Comment: @Thomas Alignment of columns is not that important, but I would prefer right-aligned as most columns will be numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant that since you have different numbers of columns, does it matter where the columns of each dataframe fall relative to the columns of the dataframes that will be placed above or below it on the sheet?

Comment: @Thomas Oh, I see. No, it does not matter, I expect that every data frame will start in column A and continue till the end od data frame without any special alignment.

Comment: My first thought was: "I'm sure you can do that with `write.xlsx` from the `xlsx` package", but it turns out that you can't at the moment.  Just sent a patch to the package maintainer, so soon it should be possible to do there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
dflc <- lapply(dfl, function(x) {
  as.data.frame(sapply(x, function(y) {as.character(y)}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  })

out <- rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(names(dflc),
        function(x) {
          rbind(
            c(x,rep('',ncol(dflc[[x]])-1)),
            names(dflc[[x]]),
            setNames(dflc[[x]],NULL),
            '')
        }
      ))

out[is.na(out)] <- ''
out <- as.data.frame(out)

out
```

The `out` object looks like:

```
        1 2 3 4 5
1     df1        
2       a b c d  
3       1 e 1 a  
4       2 f 2 b  
5       3 g 3 c  
6                
7     df2        
8       d b e f  
9       1 1 1 a  
10      2 2 2 b  
11      3 3 3 c  
12      4 4 4 d  
13               
14    df3        
15      g b h i  
16      b 1 1 a  
17      c 2 2 b  
18      d 3 3 c  
19      e 4 4 d  
20      f 5 5 e  
21               
22    df4        
23      j b k l t
24    1.4 a 1 a 7
25    2.4 b 2 b 8
26 3.4588 c 3 c 9
27               
28    df5        
29      m b n o  
30      1 1 1 a  
31      2 2 2 b  
32      3 3 3 c  
33      4 4 4 d  
34               
35    df6        
36      p b q r s
37      1 1 1 a 4
38      2 2 2 b 5
39      3 3 3 c 6
40      4 4 4 d 7
41      5 5 5 e 8
```

Comment: I think this is going the right direction, but currently it generates a lot of warnings and if you check the result some of the column names are not present.

Comment: @TomasGreif The warnings are because your dataframes contain factors. It has nothing to do with the solution per se. And yes, it's imperfect, but might get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I've modified your answer - fixed factor handling and added data frame name to results. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TomasGreif Edits look great!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the `XLConnect` package.  I'm sure you can tinker with this to get exactly what you need, but it's most of the way there.

```
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("sampleFile.xlsx", create = T) 
createSheet(wb, name = 'Sheet1')                  
dflNrow <- 0                                      
for(df in dfl){
  dflNrow <- dflNrow + nrow(df)  
  XLConnect::writeWorksheet(wb, df, sheet = 'Sheet1', startRow = dflNrow)
}
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

With this script, the data frames will not be separated by a space or a 'name', but the header row is shaded gray.